# Полоска по ширине блока

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо сделать полоску по ширина блока (как показано на скриншоте), но, почему-то, получается только по ширине текста/картинки.

[image]

CSS:

```
    .navbar {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 70px;
}
.navbar .home {
    width: 42px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(images/nav-logo.png) no-repeat;
}
.navbar .dashboard {
    width: 24px;
    height: 22px;
    background: url(images/dashboard.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar li {
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.navbar li a {
    margin-left: -15px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li class="home"></li></a>
                <li class="dashboard"><a href="#">Прокси</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Результат:

[image]

Просьба, также, указать на ошибки верстки, если имеются. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Привет, у вас явная ошибка:

```
<a href="#"><li class="home"></li></a>
```

Нельзя `<li>` оборачивать в какой то тег, кроме `<ul>`.

Я бы сверстал так:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="image/pic.png" alt="" />
        <p>Proxy</p>
    </a>
</nav>
```

При таких стилях:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px; left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

nav a:last-child { border: 0; }

nav img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/Zjfyf/1/

Comment: @Олег Б, большое спасибо!